# iOS: Tabbar Tint Color

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, tintcolor

I'm creating a TabBar in code:

```
self = [super init];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    self.tabBarController.navigationController.delegate = self;

    //Build Model
    NSArray *topLevelControllers = [self buildTopLevelControllers];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:topLevelControllers animated:NO];

    //Inbox will be lead navigation
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = kSelectedIndex;

    [self.view addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    self.tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = @[];


    return self;
}
```

In App Delegate I have the following code for Tint:

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[ColorUtils globalTintColor]];
```

**Problem:**  When the App launches, all the icons in the Tab Bar are tinted with the global color.  When I select one and then unselect it, they go back to Grey (images default color).

**Desired Result:**  When the App launches, all the buttons are Grey (Grey is the image color in the PNGs).  When I tap on the tab bar icon, the color changes to the global tint color.

**Tried:**  In the App delegate, I have added the following code and it does NOT work:

```
TabBarVC *tabBarVC = [[TabBarVC alloc]init];
tabBarVC.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor greyColor];
tabBarVC.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [STColorUtils globalTintColor];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [ColorUtils globalTintColor]}];


[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[ColorUtils globalTintColor]];
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarVC];
```

However, if I comment out:

```
//[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[ColorUtils globalTintColor]];
```

The icons do appear Grey, but the global tint color is iOS7 default: Blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known issue with selectedImageTintColor in iOS 7. Last I checked this has yet to be resolved. So remove -

```
tabBarVC.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [STColorUtils globalTintColor];
```

Also you want to use the UITabBar's appearance so replace

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[ColorUtils globalTintColor]];
```

with

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[ColorUtils globalTintColor]];
```

Comment: I also had to include: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[ColorUtils globalTintColor]];  Please adjust your answer for others to see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this is the best solution i've found so far:

```
[UIView appearance].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

// the selected image and text will still use UIView.tintColor. 
// this is to tint the unselected images until they are tapped
// [UIColor grayColor] does not exactly match the default color, but it's subtle
[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil].tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

when using swift i needed to create an objective-c file that contains a +(UIView *)viewAppearanceWhenContainedInTabBar() method to use [UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:] method as it is not available to swift :(

Answer (score 1):

change the UIWindow's tintColor property. It's applied across every UIView which is added onto this window.